# Java equivalent of .Net Solution file type

Tags: eclipse

I'm new to Java and starting to organize my first project which will be a conversion from a .Net solution with several projects attached (one GUI project and several supporting class projects).

I'm using Eclipse and I see project files, but I'm wondering is there a way to organize them into a "solution"? Something that links all the projects together. In .Net there is a solution file and you can use it to open and load all the projects and their files associated with the application.

I see package and source folder, but they seem to be project specific (one project). I created a working set, but that just seems to keep the projects together in eclipse's views.

Perhaps there is no need for this in Java for some reason, but I want to make sure I set this application up correctly initially

Comment: Read up on EAR files. Create an EAR file in eclipse then add to it your support projects and your web project.Another option (if you want to deploy the web project as a WAR file) is to build each of the supporting projects to jars and include them in the web project.

Comment: @dwb: your comment in this case should be an answer imo.

Answer (score 5):

In java we don't have this concept of "solution", we use just the project concept and the link between project, this links between projects can be made using just the reference in eclipse workspace or something of more complex like the dependency management system (ex: [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)) the project also produce an artifact of different types, you can have a jar that correspond to a simple library/program, or an war that correspond to an web application and can include more jar inside itself, and a the end you can have an ear that correspond to a complex application and can include inside itself multiple jar and war.

you can also find the explain of any type of artifact on wikipedia!